# In an java/mysql application can sql Update behave as sql Insert

Tags: java, mysql

In an database application, while testing an update button statements for some application jtable which represents a database table contents, i gained a resulting behavior with either creating a new row/record or throwing an duplicate primary key exception such being the same row/record key, with a clear update statement and syntax, actually i asked here before and i was guided to provide a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" , so i grabbed those updating lines in a new java runnable class - which worked very well and i didn't notice the difference - and it was such this counterpart parameters code example :

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class QueryTesting
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
            // create a java mysql database connection
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true", "username", "password")) {
                Statement s = null ;
                try {
                    s = conn.createStatement();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(QueryTestingForWMC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                int Result ;
                try {
                    Result = s.executeUpdate("USE myDatabase");
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(QueryTestingForWMC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt= null;
                // create the java mysql update preparedstatement
                String query = "update relativesTable set idRelativeMembers = ? , Name = ? , Picture = ? , RelationDegree = ? , persons_idPersons = ? where idRelativeMembers = ?";
                // create the mysql update preparedstatement
                preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString(1,"00002/10");
                preparedStmt.setString(2,"عبد الحفيظ أحمد عبد الفتاح الدؤري");
                preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(3, null);
                preparedStmt.setString(4, "إبن عم");
                preparedStmt.setString(5, "00002");
                preparedStmt.setString(6, "00002/10");

                // execute the java preparedstatement
                preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                preparedStmt.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }              

  }
}
```

the update code block - in the original application - mentioned with a System.out.println() hint statement to assure that is the updating statement conditional block :

```
// the mysql update statement
String selectedMemberPrimaryKey = getMembersWithoutPhotos().get(jTable5.convertRowIndexToView(jTable5.getSelectedRow())).getId() ;

System.out.println("This is an update query");

String updateStatement = "update relativesTable set idRelativeMembers = ? , Name = ? , Picture = ? , RelationDegree = ? , persons_idPersons = ? where idRelativeMembers = ?";

// create the mysql update preparedstatement
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
preparedStmt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
```

while insert condition is hinted also with an insertion hint :

```
// the mysql insert statement
System.out.println("This is an insert query");

String insertStatement = "insert into relativesTable (idRelativeMembers, Name, Picture, RelationDegree, persons_idPersons) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


// create the mysql insert preparedstatement
preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
preparedStmt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
```

The database table is related with another table through persons_idPersons foreign key, till now, i cannot figure out how the behavior would came from, however, is there is a condition(s) that may leads to the insertion behavior for the jdbc sql update statement ?

---

NEW NOTION :

I have tried to prepare the update query by other prepare statement way such :

```
   System.out.println("This is an update query");
   String updateStatement = "update relativesTable set idRelativeMembers = '00002/20' , Name =' أحمد عبد البارئ الثبنيتي ', Picture = null , RelationDegree =' عم ', persons_idPersons = '00002' where idRelativeMembers = '00002/10'";                       

   // create the mysql update preparedstatement
   preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
```

and it has worked very well !

---

The whole UPDATE statement block in the jbutton for saving data to the database is - while i have commented the whole INSERT statement block in the jbutton, and still UPDATE works in such INSERT behavior! - :

```
    try
    {
        // the mysql update statement
        String selectedRelateivesMemberPrimaryKey = getMembersWithoutPhotos().get(jTable5.convertRowIndexToView(jTable5.getSelectedRow())).getId() ;

        System.out.println("This is an update query");
        String updateStatement = "update relativesTable set idRelativeMembers = ? , Name = ? , Picture = ? , RelationDegree = ? , persons_idPersons = ? where idRelativeMembers = ?";                       

        // create the mysql update preparedstatement
        preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
        selectedRelativeMemberForUpdateId = jTextField2.getText();
        preparedStmt.setString(2, jTextField4.getText());

        if(null == jLabel17.getIcon())
        {

            preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(3, null);

        }else
        {

            Icon icon = jLabel17.getIcon();
            ImageIcon img = (ImageIcon) icon ;
            BufferedImage bI = new BufferedImage(img.getIconWidth(), img.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = bI.createGraphics();
            icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
            g.dispose();
            ImageIO.write(bI, "jpg", new File("personRelativeMemTempImage.jpg"));
            personRelativeMemImageFileForDatabase = new File("personRelativeMemTempImage.jpg");
            personRelativeMemImageFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(personRelativeMemImageFileForDatabase);
            preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(3,(InputStream) personRelativeMemImageFileInputStream,(int) personRelativeMemImageFileForDatabase.length());

        }

        preparedStmt.setString(4, jTextField15.getText());
        preparedStmt.setString(5, selectedPersonForRelativeMembersId);


        preparedStmt.setString(6, selectedRelateivesMemberPrimaryKey);



        // execute the preparedstatement
        preparedStmt.execute();

        try {
            preparedStmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }                        

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        String exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
        if(exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionStringPartOne) && exceptionMessage.contains(exceptionStringPartTwo))
        {                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate Keys","error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            duplicatePrimaryKeyFlag = true ;
        }else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A Related Database Error","error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an INSERT statement to insert a new row, an UPDATE will only act on an existing record.

There is a possibility that there is an before/after UPDATE trigger defined on the table that does the INSERT but it would still be an INSERT that creates the new record, however it is called.

You could check for a trigger with

```
select * from `information_schema`.`triggers` 
where event_object_schema = 'myDatabase' 
and event_object_table = 'relativesTable'\G
```

However, a more likely explanation is an error in your application logic that runs the insert path rather than the update path, or both.

Comment: No triggers such 0 row(s) returned from proposed query execution, and in know that UPDATE updates existing records, and INSERT inserts new records, and thank you for guide toward application writting correction

Comment: Hope you track down your problem.

Comment: Actually cannot figure out the problem, with the same output :

This is an update query   
Got an exception!    
Duplicate entry '00003/2-00003' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I tried to change query to make sure that this is the executed query, and i changed update query to a wrong select query and it appeared in exception results as it is, so the right condition block was assured by system.out.println prints, from begining to its ending, and the executed query was assured by changing the query and the changed one was appeared in the exception results, and still cannot figure out why update behave such insert statement, either insert new record with new key, or through duplicate keys exception

Comment: I have commented the whole INSERT code condition part in the button, and the result Of UPDATE still such INSERT behavior :

This is an update query
Got an exception!
Duplicate entry '00003/1-00003' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

Preamble :

The application form was providing a selection to a person from person's jtable and then other selection to his/her relatives members from relatives jtable, and the other selection which is to a relative member brings members's row data to jtextfields to be modified and saved by a save button, and what was happening is throwing duplicate primary key exception in case of updating a member data with the same key, and in case of entering new id for key, a new member appears in the member's jtable.

Behind the Behavior :

Regardless of the state of affairs of writting this application, the problem was in superfluous using of methods at this line :

```
  String selectedMemberPrimaryKey = getMembersWithoutPhotos().get(jTable5.convertRowIndexToView(jTable5.getSelectedRow())).getId() ;
```

it was enough to retrieve the key of the relatives members jtable to update the corresponding keyed record in the relatives members database table through the id column with just :

```
  String selectedMemberPrimaryKey = jTable5.getValueAt(jTable5.convertRowIndexToView(jTable5.getSelectedRow()), 0).toString();
```

, and this mismatch led to retrieve another key and specify another record to be updated with the relative member's updating data. Thus, updating the wrong record (key column, and other columns) with the desired record data leads to duplicate primary key exception, and in case of updating the wrong record with a new data of a new relative member for a person, the new record appears in the the desired person's members jtable, which was the update of a member from another - wrong - person's members.

So, in an java/mysql application, an sql UPDATE cannot behave directly as an sql INSERT, but it may leave an INSERT effects as in this case if this wrong updated record was auto-renewable or auto-recreatable, so it would leave some INSERT behavior.

Thank you all For caring, viewing and trying to answer.